# Order by Function Results in Union Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a query that has multiple union statements where the last union statements results are derived from a function.  I want to know how to sort the resultset based on the vchLastName of the function results.  Here is the basis of the stored procedure.

```
select ID, objtype, Descr=coalesce(v.acctName, x.Descr), x.ihhid
from (
-----select statements----
UNION ALL
SELECT
            pn.iPartyID, 
            'CONTACT',
            ISNULL(vchFirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(vchLastName,'') + ' ' + 
            CASE WHEN vchGoesBy IS NOT NULL THEN '(' + vchGoesBy + ')' ELSE ISNULL(vchGoesBy,'') END,
            pn.iHHID
FROM CRM.dbo.cfn_PartyNameSearch(1, 'test') pn
WHERE pn.cPartyType = 'C'
)
 x left join tableName v on v.id = x.id
and x.ObjType='ACCOUNT'
```

I want to sort by the pn.vchLastName for CONTACT.  the other results sorting isn't a big deal honestly, and I am not able to edit the function that gives the results.

Comment: usually just comma separated names, my only issue with sorting off of the descr column is that I can't specify for it to be the vchLastName from the final union statement, I was thinking I could just put them into a temptable and sort while inserting into the temp table and union on that, but that wasn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering takes place towards the end of the query execution, at least after all the data has been selected. Therefore you will have to order the entire result set at the end of the query. IIRC there is not conditonal ordering in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This general idea will work.  You can work out the details

```
select 2 sortfield1
, whatever aliasName
from etc
union all
select 1 sortfield1
, yourFunctionResult aliasName
from etc
order by sortfield1, aliasName
```